# Reading signal from 190v magnetic pickup

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit

I am using a magnetic pickup to detect the phase and RPM of a rotating assembly. The magnetic pickup produces a pulse once per rotation when a ferrous interrupter passes the pickup.

Dependent on the speed, air gap and material that passes it, the pickup produces a pulse of up +-190v.

I would like use this pulse as an input in to a micro controller to allow calculations on RPM and phase shift against other signals.

However, I obviously cannot feed 190v directly in to a micro controller. Are there any ICs available that would either produce a discrete 5v, 0v dependant on polarity, or something similar?

I am also using a precision 18bit ADC, so would a simple voltage divider to reduce the voltage to <5v work? As a slow moving interrupter will produce a very low voltage anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"I am also using a precision 18bit ADC, so would a simple voltage divider to reduce the voltage to <5v work? As a slow moving interrupter will produce a very low voltage anyway."

Yes in principle you can just use a voltage divider, however you have to be careful to take the power into account so that you don't burn your resistors. It is also important to note that the voltage you are measuring (+-190V) is most likely the unloaded voltage out of the coil, as soon as you put a load on it (ie. the voltage divider) then the voltage will drop.

If you go ahead with the voltage divider solution it would be a good idea to put a small capacitor (maybe 100p) across the output of the voltage divider to the MCU, and also to put a TVS diode or similar across the MCU input to protect it.

Other solutions exist but they involve turning the pulse into a logic level high/low pulse ie. you will loose the voltage information but I don't know if you need it?

Comment: Thank you. I don’t need voltage information, I only need to keep the timing of the pulses. How would you produce a logic output? I was thinking it may be possible with opto-couplers but can they handle such a voltage?

Comment: The simplest way to produce a logic output would probably be to just use an op-amp. If you want a logic output then you need to decide at what voltage level (of the pulse) you want to trigger, then just use an op-amp as a comparator to trigger at the desired level. Keep in mind that you still need to use a voltage divider to lover the voltage to within the input range of the op-amp.

Comment: Don't use an op-amp as a comparator  - use a comparator as a comparator!

Comment: What variation in timing information will you tolerate? nanoseconds? microseconds? milliseconds?

Comment: A few milliseconds is tolerable